# MVC Data Annotation - Required Field not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, data-annotations

Hi I have the following cod throughout my app but with just two fields it's not working.

```
[Required]        
public string DevelopmentPM { get; set; }
```

The following test runs and passes:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SiteConstruction_MODEL_DevelopmentPM_Is_Required()
    {
        //arrange
        var propertyInfo = typeof(SiteConstructionMetadata).GetProperty    
                           ("DevelopmentPM");

        //act
        var attribute = propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), 
                        true).Cast<RequiredAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        //assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(attribute);
    }
```

My controlller looks like:

```
        TryUpdateModel(siteConstruction);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
           return View(siteConstruction);
```

I have other required fields in model and they are OK.  This field is null (I checked) but doesn't make the model invalid - so no validation and an error on save.

My View

```
    <li>
        <label for="DevelopmentPM">
            <strong>Development PM:</strong></label>
        <%= Html.TextBox("DevelopmentPM") %>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("DevelopmentPM", "*") %>
    </li>
```

I've looked at my .dbml (Linq to SQl), spelling looks ok.

I'm I missing something simple - please, going mad.

Thanks

Davy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MetadataType(typeof(SiteConstructionMetadata))] above my partial class, I took it for granted I had it there.

Next time, instead of posting snippets, I think I'll post it all - smeone wous have spotted that pretty quickly.

Davy

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make the `DataAnnotationsModelBinder` the default model binder too. Add the following in your `Global.asax.cs`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.DataAnnotationsModelBinder();
```

and make sure that you have referenced the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` assembly in your project. See [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-39-cs.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - no I have that - as I said - This exact code is working elsewhere.

I've debugged and even if I explicitly set thge field to null in the controller - the model is still valid.